# How can I change Username and Fully qualified name fields for the users programmatically?

Tags: sitecore-api, user-management

I am trying to write a code that changes the username and the user quilfied name but all the fields I found were read-only, any help?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the username for the existing sitecore users, there is no direct way to do that programmatically. Neither the user manager nor the API of Sitecore provides a way to rename a User, the only possibility would be to create a new user and set the same roles on it.

The only option would be to do change directly in the database, although I wouldn't recommend to do it, similar to how it is described [Can username be updated in Sitecore?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10954/can-username-be-updated-in-sitecore) or https://www.netzkern.de/de-de/blog/changing-usernames-sitecore